# Question on riemann sheets for function $f(z)=z^{\alpha}$ where $\alpha$ is irrational

Tags: complex-analysis

I saw in a lecture that if $f(z)=z^{\alpha}$, where $\alpha$ is an irrational number then this function has infinite sheets which means it is an infinite sheet structure but in that lecture the prof also said that $$f(z)=z^{\frac pq}$$ is $q$ sheet structure and he says that nemerator does not affect the sheet structure but the denominator does,my question is that $z^{p/q}$ the numerator does not contribute to sheets but in z^(alpha) is an infinite sheet structure,so why in z^(p/q) the numerator does not contribute but in $z^\alpha$,the numerator contribute to an infinite sheet,so what am I missing?

Comment: You wrote two true statements, and then "what am I missing?". But I don't know what you find surprising or confusing. Can you explain your question more?

Comment: Ia it corrwct now,plz answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $\alpha$ is irrational, it doesn't have a numerator or denominator, so your exact question isn't meaningful as it stands.

But it sounds like you're looking for some unified way of looking at the two cases, so here's one: given any real number $\alpha$, define
$$
D(\alpha) = \inf\{ m\in\Bbb N\colon m\alpha\in\Bbb Z\}
$$
to be the integer corresponding to the smallest multiple of $\alpha$ that is itself an integer, or $\infty$ if no such integer exists. You can check that $D(\alpha)=\infty$ if and only if $\alpha$ is irrational, and that if $\alpha=\frac pq$ in lowest terms then $D(\alpha) = q$.

The facts from your lecture can be combined to say that the Riemann surface for $f(z)=z^\alpha$ has $D(\alpha)$ sheets. (And actually the proof pretty much reflects this definition of $D(\alpha)$.)